# Работа со строками, Java

Tags: java, строки

Дана строка, необходимо удалить из нее все слова, которые начинаются и заканчиваются символами **/***.

Вот как это пытался сделать я, но все оказалось не так просто.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "asfvfaf */dsdsdsdsd*/ sdsdsadsadd */dasd*/ adasdad";
    String[] s = str.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length;i++) {
        if(s[i].contains("*/")){
            s[i].replace(s[i], " ");
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length;i++){
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Как же все тки заставить сие работать?

Comment: Слова могут разделяться не только пробелами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length;i++) {
    if(s[i].startsWith("*/") && s[i].endsWith("*/")) {
       s[i] = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
str.replaceAll("\\*\\/\\w+\\*\\/", "");
```

Или даже можете сделать сплит по этой регулярке

```
String[] words = str.split("\\*\\/\\w+\\*\\/");
```

Comment: Больше спасибо.за Ваш ответ, но все же парень выше оказался первым и, кроме того, его метод похож на то что делал я, чуть больше Вашего:)

Comment: @PavelBobrov Да ради бога!) Все имею свое право на создание своих костылей!))